# In shopify while using custom theme the shopify app functionality and css not working, Its taking the theme css as default

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api

We have used a custom theme which is not available in shopify theme store, We have used **Help Center Faq** app to display in front end, But the App css and functionality is not working and not even **displaying the template** selected in **Help Center Faq app**. Its **displaying the custom theme functionality and css** as Default Is there any way to **override** the custom theme **css and functionality** and to **use the app css and functionality**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app should have a supported template list, contact the app support team.
Additionally, it seems your theme css it's overriding the app files. That's the reason why you shouldn't use unsupported themes unless you know what you are doing. Nevertheless, you can disable the theme css by creating a new layout file without the main css file in the header and only using the app css specific for that page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).